# Recurrence relation for a string over the letters $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that each $A$ appears before $C$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> Find a recurrence relation for the number of strings of length $n$ that's composed of the letters $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that each $A$ appears before $C$.

$a_n=\begin{cases} A\text{______} = a_{n-1} \\
 B\text{______}= a_{n-1} \\
C\text{______}= 3^{n-1} \text{ all the strings without A}\\
D\text{______}= a_{n-1}\end {cases}$

So $a_n=3a_{n-1}+3^{n-1}$

Other than $C$ they all are trivial, but with $C$, can I force $A$ to be left out?

Comment: Shouldn't $a_n$ be equal to something in $\{A,B,C,D\}$, and not a power of $3$?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones What do you mean?

Comment: Is this the problem: Find a recurrence relation for *the number of* strings of length $n$ over the letters $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that each $A$ appears before $C$?

Comment: Yes @RebeccaJ.Stones

Comment: What do you mean by "can I force $A$ to be left out"?  Everything you wrote looks good.  Are you trying to solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: @MarcusM I mean can the appearances of $A$ in the string be counted out?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you're asking, but if the string starts with $C$, then yes, there necessarily will be no $A$'s appearing in that string.  You're reasoning in the problem is correct, and I believe the recurrence relation is as well.

Comment: Are A's supposed to be immediately before C's? If not, then I think you're right. Else, you should work on the number of strings starting with A.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it be recursive? I actually found it easier to compute directly.

Answer (score 0):

(*Note*: Here, I have assumed each $A$ appears directly before a $C$.)

*Hint*: We say a sequence is *good* if every $A$ is followed by a $C$.  A good length-$n$ string has one of two possible forms:

- it is a good length-$(n-1)$ string with one of $\{B,C,D\}$ appended, or
- it is a good length-$(n-2)$ string with $AC$ appended.

This should give a clue as to what the recurrence relation relation should look like.

For the boundary case: we observe that $a_0=1$ and $a_1=3$.